# I'm getting this error when I'm intsalling tensorflow-gpu version. How to solve this?

Tags: tensorflow

This is the error I'm getting in command prompt when I'm trying to import tensorflow into python3.5:

```py
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                
File "D:\S7\ml_spl\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>                                                                                                      
from tensorflow.python import *                                                                                                                                                                                  
File "D:\S7\ml_spl\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>                                                                                               
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow                                                                                                                                                                  
File "D:\S7\ml_spl\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>                                                                                      
raise ImportError(msg)                                                                                                                                                                                          
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                      
File "D:\S7\ml_spl\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in 
swig_import_helper                                                                   
return importlib.import_module(mname)                                                                                                                                                                            
File "D:\S7\ml_spl\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\importlib\__init__.py", 
line 126, in import_module                                                                                                               
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                                                                                                                                                      
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import                                                                                                                                                     
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load                                                                                                                                                  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                                                                                         
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec                                                                                                                                                
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 938, in create_module                                                                                                                                          
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed                                                                                                                                     
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                   
File "D:\S7\ml_spl\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>                                                                                      
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *                                                                                                                                                       
File "D:\S7\ml_spl\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in 
<module>                                                                             
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()                                                                                                                                                               
File "D:\S7\ml_spl\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in 
swig_import_helper                                                                   
return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')                                                                                                                                                    
File "D:\S7\ml_spl\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\importlib\__init__.py", 
line 126, in import_module                                                                                                               
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                                                                                                                                                    
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
```

I'm seeing the above error when I'm trying to install tensorflow gpu version in an anaconda environment with python3.5 and other dependencies installed. Can someone tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install cudnn 6.0 and cuda 8? This [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9469) suggests that either those are not properly installed or you have the wrong version.

Instructions on what version and steps for installation for gpu support are on the [tensorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/)

Comment: I have cudnn 7.0 and cuda 9. These are latest versions. are they causing me this trouble?

Comment: Yes, tf will support [cudnn 7.0 in version 1.4](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/RELEASE.md) but not yet in the current version (1.3)

Comment: What version of tensorflow-gpu did you install?

Comment: tensorflow-gpu v1.3. what can i do now to get my tensorflow working with gpu support.

Comment: You should follow the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) to set that up. But before installing cudnn/cuda again, make sure your PATH is correcly setup with the one you have. (I assumed you have windows)